# Database server accessed is the client's Database connection

Tags: mysql, database, angular, spring-boot

I am trying to setup a local server for testing which I am planning to host the following:

1. Spring-Boot Application for the Backend Application (port:8080)
2. Angular 4 App for the Frontend Application (port:4200)
3. MySql Database for the Database (port:3306)

When I am trying to test using the local server, everything works fine.
The problem occurs when I try to access the server from another PC. I can't seem to access the MySql Database of the server from another PC through my frontend app.

Problem:

1. access using the server:

   ```
   localhost:4200/login - able to login (connects to the server's MySql DB)
   ```
2. access using another PC:

   ```
   192.168.179.18:4200/login -unable to login (connects to the other PC's MySql DB)
   NOTE: 192.168.179.18 is the server's IP address.
   ```

It seems that when I try to access the frontend app from another PC, it is trying to connect to the other PC's local MySql Database.

How do I configure this so that where ever I access the server, it will access the server's MySql Database??

btw, my application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_app_database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: Did you check database privileges?

Comment: @pvpkiran - yes, I added a GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* on the server's MySql Database

Comment: How does your database configuration look like. Is it in application.properties?

Comment: @pvpkiran - yes it is. although it is written as 'localhost:3306' in the application.properties which is in the server I am trying to create

Comment: Can you put that code as well. And also can you explain what exactly you mean by "The problem occurs when I try to access the server from another PC"

Comment: is the server on the same local subnet? You cannot access 192.168.x.x addresses from outside your local subnet.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - yes it is in the local subnet. I am able to access the frontend app and view the login page from another PC.

Comment: 'Unable to login' is not a problem description. You have to provide the *actual error message.*

Comment: @EJP - actually sir the problem description is:It seems that when I try to access the frontend app from another PC, it is trying to connect to the other PC's local MySql Database.

How do I configure this so that where ever I access the server, it will access the server's MySql Database??

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause and a solution. It turns out that in the FrontEnd App, it is hardcoded there to connect to localhost:8080 so where ever I access it, it will try to locate localhost:8080. When I was testing this, I was running the backend app(port 8080) on the other PC that's why it accessed the other PC's MySql Database.

What I did was changed the hardcoded localhost:8080 to 192.168.179.18:8080 so that it will communicate with the backend app on my server.